# Как изменить ссылку в laravel при публикации вместо localhost, чтобы выдавало avgust.apt0.ru

Tags: laravel, nginx, localhost

Публикую Laravel 9.0 на хостинг при помощи nginx. Все настроено, но вот когда пытаюсь нажать на какую либо кнопку, чтобы открылась следующая страница `avgust.apt0.ru/sort/1` перебрасывает на `localhost:8000/sort/1`
Но если пытаюсь самостоятельно прописать ссылку, то работает, а при нажатие на какую либо кнопку перекидывает.

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте `server_name` в вашем конфигурационном файле Nginx
2. Проверьте APP_URL в .env
3. Если используете url-генераторы (например, route() или url()) проверьте корректность формирования ссылок.
4. Если используете именованные маршруты проверьте, что используете route() вместо хардкода.

Answer (score 0):

В Laravel домен указывается в файле .env в параметре APP_URL. В нем указывается ссылка до корня проекта.

В вашем случае вы либо скопировали файл .env с локального компьютера и не изменили настройки, либо вообще не скопировали этот файл, и значение для данного параметра берется по умолчанию.

Для исправления ошибки вам надо на хостинге, в корне вашего проекта, найти файл .env и отредактировать его. Изменить APP_URL и указать корректную ссылку.